# Need to identify all the ID's that were created with in a window of +/- 10 mins of date with the same user id using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Need to identify all the ID's that were created with in a window of +/- 10 mins of date with the same user id.

```
ID|user| Date              
--|----|-------------------         
1 |abc |2020-02-02 10:01:00
2 |abc |2020-02-02 10:09:00
3 |def |2020-02-02 10:17:00
4 |def |2020-02-02 11:00:00
5 |abc |2020-02-02 10:17:00
```

### Desired o/p:

```
ID|user| Date              | CNT
--|----|-------------------|---         
1 |abc |2020-02-02 10:01:00|1
2 |abc |2020-02-02 10:09:00|2
3 |def |2020-02-02 10:17:00|1
4 |def |2020-02-02 11:00:00|0
5 |abc |2020-02-02 10:17:00|1
```

I am trying to solve this with pandas. Please provide some inputs on how this can be achieved,data volume will go up to 100k records.

### Approach taken:

I created two columns,as date_plus_10 and Date_minus_10. Then I created a nested loop to parse through the data one by one and check if date is between date_plus_10 and Date_minus_10 and has the same user. But its taking long time to execute this.

In the below code 37 and 36 are the location for the date_plus_10 and Date_minus_10 ,23 is date column,15 is user and 38 is the flag/counter.

```py
for i in range(0,100):
    time_range=DateTimeRange(data_rr_NAN.iloc[i,37],data_rr_NAN.iloc[i,36])
    for j in range(i+1,100):
        if (((data_rr_NAN.iloc[j,23] in time_range) == True) & (data_rr_NAN.iloc[j,15] == data_rr_NAN.iloc[i,15])):
            data_rr_NAN.iloc[i,38] += 1
```

Comment: How have you tried to solve this so far? In what way were your attempts unsuccessful?

Comment: Why the CNT for ID 2 is 2? If you are counting within the same user id, then there's only ID = 1 which qualifies, so isn't the CNT be 1?

Comment: @TYZ:yes you are correct, I have edited the sample data.

Comment: Also, why is ID 3 having CNT 1, ID 4 is more than 10 minutes away, so shouldn't it have CNT 0?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few variations of using the `.rolling()` operation with a time-based window size, but it seems to have a bunch of limitations that make it challenging to use for this use case.

Here's a simple approach that iterates through the DataFrame and finds the rows that fall into the window. I suspect there is a much more efficient way to do this, but it might be fast enough for your situation.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

create_user_log = np.array(
    [[1, pd.Timestamp('20200202 10:01:00'), 'abc'], 
     [2, pd.Timestamp('20200202 10:09:00'), 'abc'],
     [3, pd.Timestamp('20200202 10:17:00'), 'def'],
     [4, pd.Timestamp('20200202 11:00:00'), 'def'],
     [5, pd.Timestamp('20200202 10:17:00'), 'abc'],
     [6, pd.Timestamp('20200202 11:09:00'), 'abc'],
     [7, pd.Timestamp('20200202 11:56:00'), 'def'],
     [8, pd.Timestamp('20200202 12:00:00'), 'def'],
     [9, pd.Timestamp('20200202 12:05:00'), 'abc'],
     ])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=create_user_log, columns=["id", "date", "user"])

df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

counts = []

for row in df.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas'):
  win = df[(row[0] - pd.DateOffset(minutes=10)):(row[0] + pd.DateOffset(minutes=10))]
  counts.append(len(win[win['user']==row.user]))

df['cnt'] = counts
display(df)
```

Output:

```
                    id  user cnt
date            
2020-02-02 10:01:00 1   abc 2
2020-02-02 10:09:00 2   abc 3
2020-02-02 10:17:00 3   def 1
2020-02-02 10:17:00 5   abc 2
2020-02-02 11:00:00 4   def 1
2020-02-02 11:09:00 6   abc 1
2020-02-02 11:56:00 7   def 2
2020-02-02 12:00:00 8   def 2
2020-02-02 12:05:00 9   abc 1
```

I'm not a fan of using `itertuples()`, but since we've indexed on `date`, the work done in each iteration should be fairly fast.